# How to understand the first type of pair?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ recently and am confused by this data type:

```
pair<map<string, size_t>::iterator, bool> ret =
            word_count.insert(make_pair(word, 1));
```

It should be easy to see that we’re defining a pair and that the second type of the
pair is bool. The first type of that pair is a bit harder for me to understand.
If there were no scope operator or iterator, it would be easy. But after adding `:: iterator` is it iterator type or the `map<string, size_t>` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iterator` is a nested type inside of the `std::map` class.

The first member of the `pair` is an `iterator` to an element in the `map`. The `insert()` method returns an `iterator` to the element that was inserted, or to the  element that prevented the insertion.

The `bool` in the `pair` indicates whether the insertion was successful or not, ie whether the returned `iterator` is to a new element or an existing element, respectively.

Comment: Is it necessarily a nested type? I suppose for `map` it probably is, but it doesn't actually have to be, right?

Comment: @NathanPierson in this case, yes, it is a nested type. As evident by the use of the scope operator.

Comment: Does that imply it's actually implemented as a nested type? After all isn't it entirely likely that `std::vector<int>::iterator` is just an `int*` not any user-defined class at all, nested or otherwise? I might just be thinking of a slightly different meaning of "nested type" than your usage.

Comment: what's does work_count looks like if the insertion is successful?

Comment: @NathanPierson Whether `iterator` is declared as just a raw pointer or as a custom class, it doesn't matter.  It is still a nested type inside of `map` or `vector` or whatever. The actual type is an implementation detail.

Comment: @jakey whether the insertion is "successful" or not just means whether the requested `word` already existed in the `map` or if it was inserted anew.  Either way, the `word` will exist in the `map` after `insert()` exits, and the returned `iterator` will point at that entry.

Answer (score 0):

As you write yourself, the first type is `map<string, size_t>::iterator`

So what you have is a pair of <iterator, bool>, where the iterator is a `map<string, size_t>` iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the definition of `map<string, size_t>` is a statement like `typedef [something] iterator;` or `using iterator = [something];`. It introduces `map<string, size_t>::iterator` as the name for the iterator type associated with `map<string, size_t>`. So it's an iterator type, but it's specifically the iterator for the `map<string, size_t>` container.